# MySQL - Update images name in database from .jpg to .png

Tags: mysql, database

I need help in updating my database,
I have a column named 'questionLink' in table 'question'
which contains names of the images, (image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg)
there are 100s of images, and i have to remane with .png extension...

I firstly trying to show the records with this query, which is no way near to the solution.

> SELECT * FROM question WHERE "questionLink" LIKE '%.jpg%'

Any help will be appriciated.
Thanks

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
UPDATE question
  SET questionLink = REPLACE(questionLink, '.jpg', '.png');
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ccfb/1)** demo

Further reading [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Comment: Just be careful that `.jpg` doesn't occur elsewhere in `questionLink`.

Comment: EXACTLY.... Thanks for quick response.... It really did the work for me..

Comment: yes, eggyal... There isn't. Thanks